# Shell replacements stall inside of shared vagrant folder

Tags: bash, vagrant, zsh, fish

Recently while at work we were given an older version of ubuntu (12.04) to work with on a vagrant machine.

I wanted to migrate over to fish or zsh due to them being way better then default bash but I'm encountering a weird error where if I navigate to the /vagrant folder (shared onto the local machine as well) every command I run stalls for 5-10 seconds. Outside of the folder it does fine and has no stalling problems.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some stat or something taking too long to finish. I will suggest to run strace on bash (if you have patient for that :) ).

Such stat can be for example called from your PROMPT, it's common to have there CWD.

I will suggest to not run commands from there if not necessary. You can call commands outside and provide path to there.

Ofcourse you can play with sharing, there is probably some weak point.